# Delete key assigned to a keyboard shortcut and now doesn't work

Tags: shortcut-keys

I posted this to the ubuntuforums, but got no answer there, so I'm trying here:

While going over the keyboard shortcuts (System> Preferences> Keyboard Shortcuts), I accidentally assigned the delete key to a shortcut. I backspaced and cancelled, but next time I pressed "delete" the key didn't work. I tried creating a new shortcut called Delete and this got me a weird pop up saying "Error while trying to run (Delete) which is linked to the key (Delete)". I removed the shortcut, but it's still assigned.

I deleted the custom shortcut, but to no avail. Any ideas? this drives me bonkers, as it's such a used key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is to go to the `gconf-editor` and edit the binding in `/apps/metacity/global_keybindings/` or `/desktop/gnome/keybindings` keys.

Answer (score 6):

### Remove an unwanted keyboard shortcut

Open the dialogue in *System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts* and select the entry you need to delete:

[image]

Once the entry is selected you can either enter a new shortcut, or in case you want to disable a shortcut for this action press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (not *Delete* as this is a key that could be assigned as shortcut as well). You can close the window then.

**Please reboot your system for disabling a shortcut to take effect**

Comment: That is exactly not what I needed, since this is what I done and it didn't work

Comment: Of course I did test this procedure! This confirmed your findings that deleting the shortcut has no immediate effect. However on my system **after a reboot** everything was reset as expected. Glad that @arrange's solution worked for you.

Comment: This worked for me, much simpler than gconf.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but after reading the man page for dpkg it makes sense. If you run this command it should return the keyboard short cuts to there default.

```
sudo dpkg -configure -a
```

Hope this solves your problem