# Creating Custom Short cut Keys Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, command-line, customization

I used to have my own shortcut keys to minify all the CSS and JS files for my websites after I saved the original larger version of the file. But that was on Ubuntu 11.04 and now I cannot figure out for the life of me to get the `Alt + Shift + E` to run my command. Anyone know what files to edit or what options screens to go through to complete this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This answer (entry for 11.10) is still valid for 12.04: http://askubuntu.com/a/69161/3940. For removal of shortcut see also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30584/delete-key-assigned-to-a-keyboard-shortcut-and-now-doesnt-work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like carnendil has mentioned. There is a tab entitled, "Shortcuts" in the "keyboard" option from "all settings". Down to the left, there is the option, "Custom Shortcuts". Use (+) and (-) to add or remove shortcuts!

For instance, to add the shortcut for (System monitor), press (+), a small prompt will ask you to enter the short cut name and command,

Name: `System monitor`
Command: `gnome-system-monitor`

After pressing apply, the short cut will be disabled. Click on the word (disable) and press on the keys combination for your shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I think you are looking for Keyboard in System Configuration. There you'll find a tab named Shortcuts.

Comment: Nope, there's no option there to add your own shortcuts to the system :/