# How to edit GRUB file at /etc/default/

Tags: grub2, permissions, editing

I was trying to edit GRUB file at `/etc/default/` for fixing the brightness issue.

But I am unable to do that as there is no option to save GRUB file after edit. This may be due to some permission issue.

How should I edit this file?

And issue I am trying to fix is: ["display brightness problem with ubuntu 13.04"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288265/display-brightness-problem-with-ubuntu-13-04)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to open the file as root.

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

On 13.04 or later you might have to first install gksu:

```
sudo apt-get install gksudo
```

See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Comment: I'd also like to point out that if you're running LXDE or XFCE you can use xedit instead of gedit while in a root terminal.