# Brightness in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: brightness

I have installed Ubuntu 64-bit 13.10 today. But the brightness is too much even in the least possible value. How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the brightness of the display itself? Look at this post for more help, it seems to be more along the lines of your problem which is likely a driver specific issue

[stack related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288265/display-brightness-problem-with-ubuntu-13-04)

Answer (score 0):

you can type brightness in the dash and change the setting.

it seems there is something wrong with the brightness keyboard shortcut for 13.10

http://news.softpedia.com/news/Ubuntu-14-04-and-Ubuntu-13-10-Still-Plagued-by-Brightness-Settings-Bug-Solution-420733.shtml

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.