# Why does my custom shortcut reappear unexpectedly?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I created a custom shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> that calls `x-terminal-emulator`. For some reason, it does not work (nothing happens when hitting the mapping).

When I remove the shortcut, the built-in `Launch terminal` shortcut (which is also set to the same mapping) opens the terminal window as expected.

The problem is when I restart my session after deleting the shortcut, it is recreated in the custom shortcut window.

Do you have any idea why this shortcut is always recreated automatically after restarting a session? Do you have any idea how to fix this?

I can't find a configuration file in my home that contains the `x-terminal-emulator` string. I am running 12.04 Desktop.

Comment: I can see no difference between them, because my default terminal is precisely this x-terminal-emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it well because your idea is wrong.

You don't have to create a *new* short-cut or assign it or nothing (even when it could work), you must [change your default terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/70540/62483).

To set **x-terminal-emulator** as your default terminal, so it will open when you enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, you must open the terminal (it sounds recursive) and enter the following command:

```
gconftool --type string --set /desktop/gnome/applications/terminal/exec x-terminal-emulator
```

---

If you have problems trying to delete your *custom shortcut*, I can tell you that after remove the shortcut **you must restart your computer** to take effect. But if it doesn't work you should see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/30584/62483) where you will find information related.

Comment: This does not answer my question. I know gconftool is the proper way to define the default terminal. But before knowing it, I tried to use a custom shortcut that I now want to remove. My problem is when I remove it, it always reappears.

Comment: Oh, so you are saying that right now you are opening `x-terminal-emulator` **with Ctrl+Alt+T or with other short-cut**? Are you saying that you want to open **what terminal with what command**? I can't understand you..

Comment: I am saying that when I remove the custom shortcut I added before knowing the gconftool way of updating the default terminal, the Ctrl+Alt+T shortcut works. But when I close my session and reopen it, the custom shortcut reappears. I want to know why this shortcut reappears automatically and how to stop this.

Comment: *why this shortcut reappears automatically* Are you referring to `Ctrl+Alt+T` or to your custom short-cut created?

Comment: My custom shortcut

Comment: And how are you removing the custom shortcut? In Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts

Comment: @greydet See my answer, I added information that could be useful. Tell me your results.

Comment: I tried to remove the keybinding using the gconf-editor as described in the other question you referred but it does not work either

Comment: Oh, if so then I think that you should report it as a [bug](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/62483). Because you have tried with all the possible methods.

Comment: Perhaps try with dconf-editor, too. I don't know if they edit the same things. Can you change the shortcut to something else so it sticks?